# Cities Population Sources

Tags: gis, geospatial, data-mining

I am trying to create dataset with "all" cities and their population.  I am using this list of cites - http://geonames.nga.mil/ Now I am trying to get population population for all them.

Can you suggest good sources of this kind of data?

Comment: Why this question was downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

The U.S. Census Bureau has this data. There are three links I will supply to you.

The first, is the general link to [The American FactFinder](http://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml). From here you can do searches for all kinds of [census] data, by many geographical units. This is the broadest link I will provide-- I recommend the "advanced search" feature.

From this same page you can navigate to downloading a few prepared datasets specifically pertaining to population. You are given a handful of geographical resolutions including micro- and metropolitan areas and county/state. The link is [here](http://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/download_center.xhtml)

Thirdly, the U.S. Census bureau also supplies what are called TIGER-line shape files. These are meant to be used with geographical software such as ArcGIS for plotting data across geographical regions. Within these data are also tables that contain such population-specific data that you are looking for. I include these, located [here](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html), mostly for the sake of thoroughness.

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems it contains data only for US. It is good start but I am still looking for international data as the NGA data set contains 7M entries about world-wide places.